# refresh page only if csv line count is changed

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, csv

From the research I have done I think I may have to use Ajax but i'm not really familiar with it AND i can't seem to find the right answer for my function.

I am not using a database (perhaps I should but im looking for a shorter term fix). I am using a csv file that a user's data is input to using PHP.

my php is looping through the csv file and displaying a table with the content. Its just a single column of twitter usernames.

```
<php?    
echo "<table>\n";
$file = file("Twitter.csv");
$file = array_reverse($file);
foreach($file as $f){
$string=$f; 
$string=str_replace("\r\n","",$string);
    echo "<tr>\n";
            echo "<td><a href='http://twitter.com/".$string."' target='_blank'><img src='https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=".$string."&size=bigger' border='0'></td>\n<td>\n<a href='https://twitter.com/".$string."' class='twitter-follow-button' data-show-count='false' data-lang='en' data-size='large'>Follow @".$string."</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src='//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,'script','twitter-wjs');</script>";
    echo "</td>\n</tr>\n";
    }
echo "\n</table>";
?>
```

Once the user authorizes the twitter application and I get their username, they will be redirected to the page that lists others names to follow. However, I want that page to update when the linecount of the csv file changes.

I need to be able to run the script every x seconds to get the linecount and if it has changed to refresh.

I imagine the logic is as simple as:

```
$linecount = count(file('Twitter.csv'));
every x seconds{
    $checkcount = count(file('Twitter.csv'));
    if ($checkcount != $linecount){
     refresh page
    }
 }
```

I feel like the logic is right - I am just not educated enough to figure out how to write that code to work.

If the file does not update, the page will not refresh, but the code will still execute every x seconds until the files does change.

Comment: How about if you just check the file modified timestamp? filemtime()?

Comment: The question would still be unanswered though - how could i check the timestamp or linecount every x seconds and refresh the page if it is different?

Comment: sorry, I was thinking that timestamp might be more efficient; you can refresh page using header('Location: /URL'); I would look into ajax solution though...

Comment: Yeah - was hoping for something more simple. I know how to get the timestamp or line count. I just dont know how to make the code execute every x seconds. I will just keep on trucking. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution can be done in a few steps (untested):

- Your PHP script writes the current value of `filemtime('Twitter.csv')` into a block of JavaScript:

> ```
> echo '<script>var currentTS = ', (int)filemtime('Twitter.csv'), ';</script>';
> ```

- Create a small PHP script that returns the modification time of `Twitter.csv`:

> ```
> echo json_encode(array('ts' => filemtime('Twitter.csv')));
> ```

- Write a JavaScript function that fetches the timestamp via AJAX using some simple jQuery:

> ```
> function myFunction() {
>     $.ajax({
>       url: '/path/to/check_mod_time.php',
>       timeout: 2000, // don't wait too long
>       success: function(data) {
>         if (currentTS < data.ts) {
>             location.reload();
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

- Let your function get called every X seconds using `setInterval()`:

> ```
> setInterval(myFunction, 5000) // run every 5 seconds
> ```

Comment: Nice, but you might want to add that jQuery is required for your solution to work.

Comment: I like where this is going - in this case how would I call the function? is .ajax() my function name?

Comment: @Chris No, your function will have that piece of code inside of it.

Comment: Okay - so I have all of this set but the page does not reload when the file is updated. Here is what i got from your solution...
Additional comments with what I added:

Comment: On the page that has the output of users I added:
<?php
echo '<script>var currentTS = ', (int)filemtime('Twitter.csv'), ';</script>';
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'load.php',
    timeout: 2000, // don't wait too long
    success: function(data) {
        if (currentTS < data.ts) {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
});}
setInterval(myFunction, 5000);
</script>

Comment: And I created another page called load.php with the following code in it:
<?php
echo json_encode(array('ts' => filemtime('Twitter.csv')));
?>

Comment: @Chris well, that looks about right; seems you have to do some debugging using Chrome or Firebug then to find out what's working and what not :)

Comment: Thanks for understand exactly what I have been looking for. This helped me understand a lot.